# What is the remainder of $\frac{x^{2020} + x^{2019}}{x - 1}$?

Tags: polynomials

$\dfrac{x^{2020} + x^{2019}}{x - 1}$

How do I find the remainder here? Long division seems not to work here

Comment: Google Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Or note that $x^{2020}+x^{2019}=x^{2020}-1+x^{2019}-1+2$...

Comment: Well, long division will work. It just takes a bit more time than one might want, and there are better ways.

Answer (score 1):

You have :

$$x^{2020}+x^{2019} = Q(x)(x-1) +R(x)$$

where $Q,R$ are two polynomials such that degree($R$) < degree($x-1$). Therefore degree($R$) $= 0$.

With $x=1$, $1+1 = 0 + R(1)$ so the remainder is equal to $2$.

Comment: @Arthur:  why did you change it to $1\color{red}-1$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Sorry, I read that line completely wrong. Changed it back.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you managed to do the division and you found a polynomial and a remainder. That means that:

$x^{2020}+x^{2019}=(x-1)P(x)+R$

Try evaluating the output of $1$ on both sides.

$1+1=0+R$

Would you look at that? The remainder is exactly $2$, which is the value of the function $x^{2020}+x^{2019}$ at $1.$

And that is the remainder theorem.

You could also go down the number theory route.

$n=x-1$

$x=n+1$

$x^{2020}+x^{2019}=(n+1)^{2020}+(n+1)^{2019}$

$\equiv 1+1 \equiv 2 \quad (\bmod n)$